# Integrating Countly with React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, countly-analytics

I have a requirement to use countly for analytics in a React.js web app.
The is built using `React.js`, `react-router-dom`, `redux`, `saga`, `material.ui`.

The countly provides an SDK for web analytics.
https://support.count.ly/hc/en-us/articles/360037441932-Web-analytics-JavaScript-

I could not find any effective way or package until now.

Anyone who has used the countly please help to answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/tree/master/samples/react) sample application in react which has the countly web sdk integration.
To integrate the countly web sdk in your application, you would first have to install the [countly-sdk-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countly-sdk-web) module in your repo.
You can then initialize countly in your index.js file like [this](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/blob/be69c3892226fb531413569d2ecd11c017b34275/samples/react/src/index.js#L10-L56).
For url tracking, please include [this](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/blob/master/samples/react/src/Location-WithEffect.js) Location component in your repo and use it within the router component like [this](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/blob/be69c3892226fb531413569d2ecd11c017b34275/samples/react/src/App-WithEffect.js#L17).

Incase you are not using function components and hooks, the sample application shared above also contains the example of the countly SDK integration with class based components.

Comment: The link is not up-to-date - sample can be found there https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/tree/master/examples/react